# Como remover um "ouvinte" que adicionei via addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

Eu costumo sempre usar a função `addEventListener` para "ouvir" alguns eventos, como `click`, conexão do Websocket e afins.

Por exemplo:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/');

ws.addEventListener('open', function () {
       // Minha lógica
});

if (window.alguma_condicao) {
    ws.addEventListener('open', function () {
         // Minha lógica
    });
}
```

No caso acima, em uma determinada situação, como eu poderia fazer pra remover todos os "ouvintes" (os callbacks, que são as funções anônimas) que adicionei através de `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Só é possível remover um listener usando a referência para a função. Ou seja, você não pode remover eventos que sejam criados com funções anônimas.

Para remover os *listeners* usando as referências, basta usar a função [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

Neste caso, mantenha-se atento ao parâmetro `useCapture` (o terceiro). Se o `addEventListener` usar este parâmetro como `true`, o `removeEventListener` precisa fazer o mesmo, caso contrário, o evento não sera removido.

Exemplo ilustrativo:

```js
const bt = document.getElementById('bt');

bt.addEventListener('click', fnClick);

function fnClick() {
  console.log('Essa é a última vez que você fez isso');
  bt.removeEventListener('click', fnClick);
}
```

```html
<button id="bt">Clique aqui</button>
```

Outra opção é remover o evento dentro da função que o adiciona. Isso é possível definindo uma função nomeada e usando o nome desta função para remover o *listener* ou usando `arguments.callee`.

```js
const bt = document.getElementById('bt');
const bt2 = document.getElementById('bt2');

bt.addEventListener('click', function fn() {
  console.log('Essa é a última vez que você fez isso');
  bt.removeEventListener('click', fn);
});

bt2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Essa é a última vez que você fez isso (2)');
  bt2.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);
});
```

```html
<button id="bt">Clique aqui</button>
<button id="bt2">Clique aqui</button>
```

Comment: mal pude ver os seus movimentos.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita Só agora que vi sua resposta XD

Comment: você enviou a sua resposta 5 segundos antes ;D

Answer (score 9):

Uma forma não muito trivial de se executar a tarefa é *interceptar* a chamada da função `addEventListener` e guardar a referência à função de algum modo, pois, como dito nas outras respostas, não seria possível remover uma função anônima (ou *arrow function*) já que não teríamos a referência desta. Se armazenarmos a referência, a solução passa a ser possível.

Considerando que tal solução pudesse ser necessária em uma aplicação em produção, não seria interessante ter que modificar todo o código, tal como nomear todas as funções anônimas ou chamar nossa função personalizada no lugar de `addEventListener`. O mais prático seria se definíssemos tal comportamento como padrão da função `addEventListener` e isso é possível reimplementando-a através de [`Element.prototype.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener). Porém, como necessitaremos da função original, precisamos criar um *backup* desta com outro nome:

```
Element.prototype._AddEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
```

> Aqui, a função `addEventListener` original passa a ser `_addEventListener`.

Para então definirmos nossa função `addEventListener` personalizada:

```
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture = false) {

    if (typeof this.listeners === "undefined") {
        this.listeners = [];
    }

    this.listeners.push({type: type, listener: listener, useCapture: useCapture});
    this._AddEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
};
```

Ou seja, quando a função for chamada, será verificado se o elemento possui um atributo `listeners`ue armazenará todas as referências dos *listeners* adicionados. Se não possuir, é definido como uma lista vazia e, após, adicionado a referência do *listener* à lista, armazenando também o nome do evento e o valor de `useCapture`. Ao final, é chamada a função `_addEventListener`, que é a função original, portanto o comportamento original da função permanece inalterado.

Agora, para removermos todos os *listeners* de um elemento, podemos definir uma nova função:

```
EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListeners = function(type = null, useCapture = false) {
    if (typeof this.listeners !== "undefined") {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++) {
            if ((type == this.listeners[i].type || type === null) && useCapture == this._listeners[i].useCapture) {
                this.removeEventListener(type, this.listeners[i].listener, useCapture);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Perceba o `s` em `removeEventListeners` para não conflitar com a função original. Basicamente a função verifica se o elemento possui uma lista de *listeners* e, se possuir, a percorre removendo todos os *listeners* condizentes com os parâmetros da função. Isto é, se definido o valor de `type`, serão removidos todos os *listeners* associados ao evento definido por `type` cujo o vajor de `useCapture` seja o mesmo que o passado por parâmetro. Se for chamado sem parâmetros, serão removidos todos os *listeners* de todos os eventos com `useCapture` falso.

Vejamos na prática:

```js
// Mantemos a função original de addEventListener:
EventTarget.prototype.originalAddEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

// Definimos uma função nova que armazena a referência dos listeners:
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture = false) {

    if (typeof this._listeners === "undefined") {
        this._listeners = [];
    }
    
    this._listeners.push({type: type, listener: listener, useCapture: useCapture});
    this.originalAddEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
};

EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListeners = function(type = null, useCapture = false) {
    if (typeof this._listeners !== "undefined") {
        for (let i = 0; i < this._listeners.length; i++) {
            if ((type == this._listeners[i].type || type === null) && useCapture == this._listeners[i].useCapture) {
                this.removeEventListener(type, this._listeners[i].listener, useCapture);
            }
        }
    }
};

// Link 1, quando pressionado, muda a cor da fonte para vermelho.
document.getElementById("a1").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    this.style.color = "red";
});

// Link 2, quando pressionado, muda a cor da fonte para azul, mas o evento é removido.
document.getElementById("a2").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    this.style.color = "blue";
});

document.getElementById("a2").removeEventListeners("click");

// Link 3, quando pressionado, muda a cor da fonte para verde. O evento é definido como useCapture=true, mas é tentado remover com useCapture=false.
document.getElementById("a3").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    this.style.color = "green";
}, true);

document.getElementById("a3").removeEventListeners("click");
```

```html
<a href="#!" id="a1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#!" id="a2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#!" id="a3">Link 3</a>
```

- O `Link 1` mantém o evento conforme adicionado;
- O `Link 2` volta ao comportamento original, pois o *listener* é removido;
- O `Link 3` mantém o evento, pois é adicionado com `useCapture=true` e tentado remover com `useCapture=false`.

Desta forma, é possível remover os *listeners* mesmo que estes estejam definidos como uma função anônima ou uma *arrow function*.

Resumo de chamadas de `removeEventListeners`:

```
// Remove os listeners do evento `click`, com useCapture=False:
element.removeEventListeners("click");

// Remove os listeners do evento `click`, com useCapture=True:
element.removeEventListeners("click", true);

// Remove todos os listeners, com useCapture=False:
element.removeEventListeners();

// Remove todos os listeners, com useCapture=True:
element.removeEventListeners(null, true);
```

Answer (score 8):

Infelizmente, o Javascript não disponibiliza uma forma de listar todos os eventos, então você terá de manter uma referência aos eventos adicionados.

Abaixo tem um exemplo de como remover um evento específico.

```js
let teste = document.getElementById("teste");
let event1 = function () {
  console.log("evento 1");
}

let event2 = function () {
  console.log("evento 2");
}

let event3 = function () {
  console.log("evento 3");
}

teste.addEventListener("click", event1);
teste.addEventListener("click", event2);
teste.addEventListener("click", event3);

teste.removeEventListener("click", event2);
```

```html
<button id="teste">Click Me</button>
```

você pode implementar o seu proprio gerenciador de Eventos.:

```js
let EventHandler = (function () {
  let EventHandler = function (objeto) {
    this.objeto = objeto;  
    this.types = {};
  };
  EventHandler.prototype.addEvent = function (type, listener) {
    if (!this.types[type])
      this.types[type] = [];
    this.types[type].push(listener);
    this.objeto.addEventListener(type, listener);
  };
  EventHandler.prototype.removeEvent = function (type, listener) {
    if (!this.types[type])
      return;
      
    var index = this.types[type].indexOf(listener);
    this.types[type].splice(index);
    this.objeto.removeEventListener(type, listener);
  };
  EventHandler.prototype.removeAllEvent = function (type) {
    if (!this.types[type])
      return;
    this.types[type].forEach(function (listener, indice) {
      this.objeto.removeEventListener(type, listener);
    }.bind(this));
    this.types[type].length = 0;
  }
  return EventHandler;
})();

let teste = document.getElementById("teste");
let handler = new EventHandler(teste);

handler.addEvent("click", function () { console.log('event 1'); });
handler.addEvent("click", function () { console.log('event 2'); });
handler.addEvent("click", function () { console.log('event 3'); });

teste.addEventListener("click", function () {
  handler.removeAllEvent("click");
  console.log('button clicado');
});
```

```html
<button id="teste">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Quero compartilhar e agregar as outras excelentes respostas, informando algumas atualizações e soluções alternativas.

---

###### Nota

<sup>Verifique se a versão de seu navegador suporta os recursos nesta resposta antes de rodar os snippets de código.</sup>

---

## Uma atualização para `addEventListener`

Talvez não tenha sido apresentado nas outras respostas a solução a seguir por uma questão de data, mas se a sua intenção se encaixar nesse caso:

1. *Quero adicionar um ouvinte a um evento, mas quero que ele execute **apenas uma vez** e depois quero removê-lo!*

As soluções do Bueno resolveriam, mas o detalhe que ele mencionou:

> *"Só é possível remover um listener usando a referência para a função. Ou seja, você não pode remover eventos que sejam criados com funções
> anônimas."*

pode ser contornado com o método a seguir.

Para atender o caso mencionado (**1**), você pode passar uma função anônima ou não anônima para o `addEventListener` e como terceiro argumento, um objeto com a opção chamada `once`. Veja:

```js
const bt2 = document.getElementById('bt2');

bt2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Por causa do `once`, vai executar somente 1 vez!');
}, { once: true }); // <- Este objeto
```

```html
<button id="bt2">Exemplo com "once"</button>
```

Com [`{ once: true }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) indicamos o seguinte (de acordo com a documentação):

> ...que o *listener*deve ser invocado no **máximo
> uma vez após ser adicionado**. **Se verdadeiro, o ouvinte seria removido
> automaticamente quando invocado**. Se não for especificado, o padrão é
> `false`.

Detalhe que no caso acima podemos trabalhar com funções anônmas ou não e não temos a necessidade de chamar `removeEventListener` para remover o *listener* de um evento.

Fique atento que esta solução usa a opção `once` que foi adicionada recentemente em navegadores e até mesmo no Node.js (`v14.5.0`). No navegador em que escrevo esta resposta (Chrome), ela foi adicionada na versão `55`. Por via de duvidas, consulte a versão do ambiente que suporta esse recurso [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

## `AbortController`

Geralmente, podemos usar esta API para cancelar chamadas HTTP feitas com `fetch`, como mencionado [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480076/como-cancelar-interromper-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-feita-com-axios/480077#480077), mas não é só isso. Podemos fazer mais com [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) e o contexto da pergunta se encaixa.

Podemos configurar o `addEventListener` com um sinal (`signal`) para que, de forma imperativa, abortemos ou removemos um `listener`.

Vamos de exemplo, adaptando o exemplo anterior, mas sem o `once`:

```
const bt2 = document.getElementById('bt2');
const bt2Controller = new AbortController();
const { signal } = bt2Controller;

bt2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Teste');
}, { signal }); // <- Desta vez, passamos o "signal" no lugar do "once"
```

Agora, vamos ter em mente o seguinte: quando o controlador (`bt2Controller`) invocar a função `abort()`, `signal` vai indicar para o *listener* para que ele seja removido. Veja o exemplo:

```js
const bt2 = document.getElementById('bt2');
const bt2Controller = new AbortController();
const { signal } = bt2Controller;

bt2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Vai ser executado somente 1 vez nesse exemplo com "AbortController"!');
  bt2Controller.abort();
}, { signal });
```

```html
<button id="bt2">Exemplo com "AbortController"</button>
```

Neste outro exemplo, eu quero remover o *listener* depois de 3 cliques:

```js
const bt2 = document.getElementById('bt2');
const bt2Controller = new AbortController();
const { signal } = bt2Controller;
let clickCounter = 1

bt2.addEventListener('click', function() {  
  console.log('Cliques: ', clickCounter);
  clickCounter++;

  if (clickCounter === 4) {
     bt2Controller.abort();
     return console.log('Máximo de cliques atingido! Vou remover o listener.');
  }
}, { signal });
```

```html
<button id="bt2">Clique 3 vezes</button>
```

Verificamos que podemos usar funções anônimas normalmente e que, principalmente, podemos remover diversos *listeners* de uma só vez sem a necessidade de ficar trabalhando em cima do `removeEventListener`. Vou adaptar um código da resposta do Tobias para exemplificar:

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btn1Controller = new AbortController();
const { signal } = btn1Controller;

let teste = document.getElementById("teste");
let event1 = function () {
  console.log("evento 1");
}

let event2 = function () {
  console.log("evento 2");
}

let event3 = function () {
  console.log("evento 3");
}

teste.addEventListener("click", event1, { signal });
teste.addEventListener("click", event2, { signal });
teste.addEventListener("click", event3, { signal });

btn1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btn1Controller.abort(); // aqui eu vou remover todos os listeners.
})
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Remover todos os listeners</button>
<button id="teste">Teste</button>
```

Veja que com `btn1Controller.abort();`, todos os *listeners* de `teste` serão removidos.

Eu tinha outros exemplos em mente, mas esses demonstrados já devem dar uma boa noção da praticidade desta API.

Agora tenha em mente que se o `once` foi algo relativamente recente, `AbortController` é ainda mais delicado em relação ao suporte. Apenas o navegador Chrome suportou esta API por completa em 2021 na versão `66` e o Node.js apenas a partir da `v15.0.0`. Consulte o link mencionado para a documentação em caso de duvidas.