# Chamar função javascript apenas uma vez

Tags: javascript, funções

Supondo que tenho um botão que ao ser clicado chama uma função javascript. Gostaria que, caso esse botão fosse clicados diversas vezes somente chamaria essa função uma vez. Tem como fazer isso?

COMPLEMENTO
Minha pergunta foi incompleta. No caso preciso fazer o seguinte: meu botão faz uma chamada ajax. Se o usuário clicar no botão inicia a chamada, caso ele clique novamente, antes da chamada ter terminado, cancela essa primeira chamada e faz uma nova, assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que é nomeada apenas no escopo em que é executada e, após executar a ação do `addEventListener`, chamar `removeEventListener` para removê-la.

Assim:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#button');

var i = 0;
    
button.addEventListener('click', function click(e) {
    i++;
    console.log("Essa função foi chamada %d vez", i);
    button.removeEventListener('click', click);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Clica aí</button>
```

Dessa forma, diferentemente de usar uma variável indicando se o botão foi clicado ou não, o ouvinte desse evento será removido, o que pode ser interessante para ganho de performance, já que você não precisa ter um ouvinte uma vez que o mesmo já não vai fazer mais nada.

Adendo:

Se você estiver usando o jQuery, você pode usar o método `one` para simplificar o trabalho:

```
$('#button').one('click', function (e) {
    // Executa somente essa vez, não mais que isso
});
```

Seria legal você dá uma olhada nessas perguntas:

- [Como remover um "ouvinte" que adicionei via addEventListener?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241566/como-remover-um-ouvinte-que-adicionei-via-addeventlistener/241572#241572)

Answer (score 0):

Coloque uma flag, fiz um pequeno exemplo:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
var clicado = false;
function myFunction() {
    if(!clicado){
        alert('ok');
        clicado = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Assim ao clicar no botão ele seta a flag como "clicado" então ao realizar o próximo click ele não vai fazer a ação.

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma flag booleana.

```js
var jaFoiClicado = false; // começa com false pra poder ser clicado pela primeira vez

function clicarBotao() {
  if (!jaFoiClicado) {
    console.log("primeira vez");
    // substitui aqui dentro pelo seu código
    jaFoiClicado = true;
  } else {
    console.log("não vai clicar de novo nao!");
    }
}

// to simulando que clicou no botão 2x chamando a função :
clicarBotao();
clicarBotao();
```

Comment: esta errado ele executa mais de uma vez o click

Comment: Ele chama a função mais de 1x, sim! Mas apenas mostra "primeira vez" uma vez. O código da função deve ficar no primeiro if (substituir o console.log("primeira vez") )

Answer (score 0):

Apos a primeira execução,o valor da variavel check sempre vai ser true, sendo assim, é possivel limitar a qtd de chamadas da função suaFunção() para apenas 1.

JS:

```
var check = false;
function suaFunção(){
    alert("");
}
function onclick(){

   if(check==false){
       suaFunção();
   }
   check = true;
}
onclick();
onclick();
```

So vai exibir o alert apenas 1 vez.