# Como cancelar/interromper uma requisição feita com Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, promises

Geralmente, eu costumo fazer algumas chamadas AJAX com a biblioteca [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Esses dias precisei de um recurso, onde eu pudesse interromper uma determinada requisição já iniciada, mas não soube como fazer.

Existe alguma maneira de finalizar uma requisição iniciada com axios?

Por exemplo, tenho arquivo `api.js` com algumas configurações padrões.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API
});


api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {

    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
})

export default api;
```

Faço minhas chamadas com Axios assim:

```js
import api from "./api";

async function obterUsuarios() {
   const {data: usuarios} = await api.get('usuarios');

   return usuarios;
}


const usuarios = await obterUsuarios();
```

Dúvidas:

- É possível cancelar uma chamada `axios` através da `Promise` retornada pelo mesmo?
- É possível fazer o cancelamento da requisição, mesmo usando `await`?

Comment: ***É possível cancelar uma chamada axios através da Promise retornada pelo mesmo?*** essa parte ficou estranho, uma `promisse` ainda não foi executada? ou foi?

Comment: @novic "... através da Promise retornada pelo axios" foi só pra não repetir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o próprio nome da interface diz, uma promessa não pode ser quebrada. Desse modo, por si só, `Promise`s não são passíveis de cancelamento no JavaScript.

No entanto, o Axios oferece um [mecanismo de cancelamento de requisições](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation).

Basicamente, você precisa criar um *token de cancelamento* e passa ao construtor da requisição. Algo assim:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;

// Criamos a origem do token de cancelamento:
const cancelTokenSource = CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/path/of/request', {
  // Passamos o token de cancelamento para o construtor da requisição:
  cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token
});

// Note que a chamada acima retorna uma promessa.
```

Note que `cancelTokenSource` (retornado pela aplicação de `CancelToken.source`) possui uma propriedade `token` (que é o *token* de cancelamento), mas também possui um método `cancel`, que deve ser usado para *cancelar* a requisição. Você pode utilizá-lo passando um motivo para o cancelamento:

```js
cancelTokenSource.cancel('Não é mais de meu interesse enviar esta requisição.');
```

Uma vez que o `cancel` seja invocado, a `Promise` que o construtor da requisição retorna será rejeitada. Você poderá, então, utilizar o `catch` para tratar essa rejeição:

```js
axios.get('/path/of/request', {
  // Passamos o token de cancelamento para o construtor da requisição:
  cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token
}).catch(function (thrown) {
  // Utilizamos o método `isCancel` para saber se o erro da rejeição veio de um cancelamento:
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // Trate o erro.
  }
});
```

Como a rejeição é notificada através da rejeição da promessa, não há problemas em tratá-la com `async`/`await`:

```js
async function doRequest() {
  try {
    const response = axios.get('/path/of/request', {
      // Passamos o token de cancelamento para o construtor da requisição:
      cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token
    });

    // Faça algo com `response`.
  } catch (thrown) {
    if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
      console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
    } else {
      // Trate o erro.
    }
  }
}
```

Como `cancelTokenSource` está "fora da requisição", você pode cancelar a operação de qualquer lugar. Só tome cuidado para não utilizar um mesmo token para mais de uma requisição, caso contrário esse mesmo *token* poderá cancelar todas as requisições em que foi utilizado ao mesmo tempo.

Se a requisição for cancelada, como já vimos acima, a promessa que o construtor da requisição (como `axios.get` ou `axios.post`) retornar é, por garantia, rejeitada. Isso significa que, uma vez que você cancele uma requisição do Axios, a promessa jamais será resolvida.

Não há menção explícita disto documentação do Axios, mas uma vez que a requisição é cancelada (utilizando `cancelTokenSource.cancel()`), ela é, de fato, abortada. Esse comportamento é comprovado pelo próprio código-fonte da biblioteca. Veja a implementação do abortamento no [adaptador `xhr`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/768825589fd0d36b64a66717ca6df2efd8fb7844/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L165) (API dos *browsers*) e no [adaptador `http`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/768825589fd0d36b64a66717ca6df2efd8fb7844/lib/adapters/http.js#L273) (módulo nativo do Node.js).

---

É um mecanismo bem similar ao [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController), que permite o cancelamento de requisições com a API nativa `fetch`.

Comment: Ótima explicação, mas fiquei com uma dúvida. Isso apenas cancela a espera pela resposta, certo? Digo, se a requisição já chegou no servidor e ainda não foi respondida, o Axios ainda dirá que foi cancelada? - Eu espero que a resposta seja "sim", mas é sempre bom confirmar :)

Comment: @RafaelTavares, não consegui encontrar nenhuma informação explícita sobre o que de fato acontece quando é cancelada além do fato de que a promessa será rejeitada. Isso significa que é garantido que, uma vez cancelada, a `Promise` retornada pelo construtor da requisição (como `axios.get`) será uma rejeitada.

Comment: Dando uma breve olhada no [código-fonte do adaptador `xhr`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L165) é possível perceber que a requisição é de fato abortada quando se executa `cancel`. A requisição também é abortada no [adaptador `http`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/http.js#L273) (módulo nativo do Node.js).

Comment: @LuizFelipe acho que entendo a dúvida do Rafael. Porque já notei, por exemplo, que em um sistema de upload que tenho, o progresso é exibido referente ao que o frontend envia para o servidor. Porém ao chegar no "100%", dependendo do tratamento feito no upload, a resposta demora pra caramba (isso pq uma coisa é envio outra coisa é o que o server tá fazendo com o upload). Não sei se nesses casos poderia ocorrer de o servidor continuar processando algo mesmo sendo cancelado, mas também não creio que isso seja um problema (dependendo do caso).